Grease pencil stroke placement onto a selected surface
When it comes to place GP strokes on surfaces, this section in blender docs says it's possible to restrict target surfaces to selected objects only. Nevertheless, I cannot see this option in blender 4.2.0, i.e. the tab only shows "Stroke Placement" and "Offset" sections but nothing like "Project Onto Selected". Has anoybody experienced this?
Thanks for any advice,
Vincent.

It's strange, the option Project Onto Selected appear in the doc with version 4.2, and yet I couldn't find it in 4.2.0 or 4.2.3 LTS.

thanks for your comment Lutzi, perhaps should I ask the dev team.

For the record, and as a reply to my initial question: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/129507

Hello, could you please provide a screenshot or quote the specific part of the documentation you're referring to? I couldn't find anything in the documentation that matches what you mentioned.

@Lutzi can you perhaps update the post with a screenshot of this Project Onto Selected? Because I cannot see this mentioned in the documentation. So that I can re-open the post.

It was removed from the doc by the dev team (see the link I stated in my previous comment).
